# Add new wpf window to another folder

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, window

I created a new folder from solution explorer of my project. i want to add my application wpf windows inside it. but i cant access their classes from MainWindow.cs file. my purpose is making things tidy and clean in my project.

questions:

1- how to add new wpf window to another folder and refrence it in visual studio 2015?

2- is it possible to change the current directory of a wpf window that was added before?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details, including a more precise problem statement than *"i cant access their classes from MainWindow.cs file"*, it's impossible to know for sure what you're doing wrong. But most likely you are having problems with the namespace.

Your C# project has a default namespace, which you can see in the project settings under the "Application" tab. This is initially set to the same name as the project.

If you add a folder to the project in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, then any new types that you put into that folder will have the folder name included in the namespace. For example, if you start with a project named "MyWpfProject" and do nothing else, the default namespace will be "MyWpfProject". But if you add a folder named "SubFolder", then any new code module added to that folder (and only that folder) will have the namespace for code in that module set not to the project's default of "MyWpfProject", but to the more specific namespace "MyWpfProject.SubFolder".

Similarly, if you want to use any types that are declared in a code module that was added to that folder, you'll need to make sure you use the correct namespace for that type. For example, add `using MyWpfProject.SubFolder;` to the top of a C# file that wants to use the type, or `xmlns:subfolder="clr-namespace:MyWpfProject.SubFolder` to a XAML file where you want to use the type.

So, with that in mind, your specific questions were:

> 1- how to add new wpf window to another folder and refrence it in visual studio 2015?

See above. You can, for example, right-click on the folder and choose "Add/Window..." from the pop-up menu. Implement the `Window` object as usual. Then where you want to use it, make sure that you use the correct namespace to access your new type, and in particular make sure you include the folder name as part of the namespace you're using.

> 2- is it possible to change the current directory of a wpf window that was added before?

You can drag and drop files within the project as you like. This will move them on the file system as well, i.e. changing the directory where the file is stored according to its new location within the project.

In this second scenario, it is important to keep in mind that Visual Studio *will not* change the namespace for existing code. If you start with your window class directly under the project in Visual Studio, and then drag that file to a folder you've created, that window class will continue to be in the top-level namespace for the project.

If you are going to rearrange your existing project code, grouping modules in folders by dragging the files there, you should consider editing the files after you've moved them so that their namespace matches their location in the project. Doing so will help ensure a consistent layout not just for the files, but also for the type names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Solution explorer, just drag and drop the files into the new folder. You can also  use 'Source Control Explorer' to rearrange the files, add existing files to the solution, etc.